# How can I scrape tagless paragraph with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the title of the following html code:

```
<FONT COLOR=#5FA505><B>Claim:</B></FONT> &nbsp; Coed makes unintentionally risqu&eacute; remark about professor's "little quizzies."
<BR><BR>
<CENTER><IMG SRC="/images/content-divider.gif"></CENTER>
```

I've tried using:

```
def parse_article(self, response):
                for href in response.xpath('//font[@color="#5FA505"]/'):
```

but the title (Coed makes unintentionally...) isn't actually embedded in any tags so I haven't been able to actually get that content. Is there a way I can get the content without it being embedded in `<p>` or any sort of tags?

EDIT: `//font[b = "Claim:"]/following-sibling::text()` works but it also grabs and displays this bottom piece of html.

```
<FONT COLOR=#5FA505 FACE=""><B>Origins:</B></FONT> &nbsp; Print references to the "little quizzies" tale date to 1962, but the tale itself has been around since the early 1950s. It continues to surface among college students to this day. Similar to a number of other college legends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that there is the `Claim:` text beforehand, locate the `font` tag by the text of its `b` child and get the *[following text sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling)*:

```
//font[b = 'Claim:']/following-sibling::text()
```

---

Demo from the [Scrapy Shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
In [1]: "".join(map(unicode.strip, response.xpath("//font[b = 'Claim:']/following-sibling::text()").extract()))
Out[1]: u'Coed makes unintentionally risqu\xe9 remark about professor\'s "little quizzies."'
```

Note that these join and strip calls should be ideally replaced by the appropriate input or output processors used inside [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html).

Comment: It works so I'm accepting the answer, but please take a look at my edit